# How can I allow other users access to my schema

Tags: oracle, database-schema

I am trying to allow other users to access my own database schema. I know how to grant permission to users for individual tables under my own schema but I would like it so that users can just create and edit tables anytime under my schema.

Comment: [Proxy User](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_grant_connect_through.htm)

Comment: Privleges to manage objects (rather than data) across schemas are powerful and shouldn't be granted lightly, and you may not be able to grant those anyway. You could look at [proxy authentication](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/dbseg/configuring-authentication.html#GUID-8A9DCA8A-0294-47D8-81B2-61A3BF4817B6) to allow those users to effectively be you, perhaps. Are you sure you want other people to be able to modify (or trash, if they aren't careful) your schema though?

Answer (score 2):

This is a bad idea. Now read on.

There isn't any way to do this out of the box. Power users (accounts with privileges CREATE ANY, ALTER ANY, etc) can do it but that's because they have rights on any schema, not just yours.

The reason for this is simply that Oracle's security model works on the `schema.object` level, and nobody has ever come up with a compelling business reason to introduce privileges at the `schema` level. A lot of Oracle's New Feature choices are driven by what paying customers want or what Oracle thinks might attract new paying customers.

So it can't be done, because, basically, hardly anybody has ever wanted to do what you want to do. And nobody wants to do it becaus it's generally a bad idea. The ability to control our schemas, to exert governance over our data and our business logic is a very powerful thing. Granting access to all the objects in our schema - especially to create or alter those objects - is a thing which should be done as rarely and as narrowly as possible.

But, if your heart is set on this course, here's a sketch of how to do it.

1. generate a script to grant (all?) privileges on (all?) objects in your schema to a named user, driving from the data dictionary view, USER_OBJECTS.
2. create a package which dynamically executes DDL (such as CREATE TABLE, ALTER TABLE, etc). Grant execute on that package to a named user.
3. write an AFTER CREATE trigger for that schema which grants privileges on created objects to the named user.

Instead of a named user you might choose to use a role, especially if you want to have multiple people creating mayhem in your schema.

Have fun!